# SQL Oracle - Running into errors after concatenating time to date and using it to find the difference in minutes between two datetimes

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm running into the following errors:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> and ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

I've tried many things and I still run into one of the errors listed above.

Here is sample data (randomly put together):

```
with sb_or_cases (log_id, surgery_date, day_of_week, in_or_dttm, out_or_dttm, minutes_in_or) as 

(
 
select 1, '2023-07-18 00:00:00', 'Monday' ,'2023-07-18 08:44:00', '2023-07-18 09:10:00', 26 from dual union all
select 2, '2023-01-24 00:00:00','Tuesday' ,'2023-01-24 12:39:00', '2023-01-24 13:28:00', 49 from dual union all
select 3, '2022-05-16 00:00:00', 'Wednesday','2022-05-16 07:30:00', '2022-05-16 08:12:00', 42 from dual union all
select 4, '2023-04-04 00:00:00', 'Thursday','2023-04-04 10:10:00', '2023-04-04 10:32:00', 22 from dual union all
select 5, '2023-07-26 00:00:00','Friday' ,'2023-07-26 08:34:00', '2023-07-26 09:20:00', 46 from dual union all
select 6, '2022-11-22 00:00:00','Saturday' ,'2022-11-22 07:24:00', '2022-11-22 08:20:00',   56 from dual union all
select 7, '2023-05-04 00:00:00', 'Sunday' ,'2023-05-04 11:44:00', '2023-05-04 12:07:00',    23 from dual union all
select 8, '2022-06-01 00:00:00', 'Monday' ,'2022-06-01 09:38:00', '2022-06-01 10:31:00',    53 from dual union all
select 9, '2022-11-17 00:00:00','Tuesday' ,'2022-11-17 07:23:00', '2022-11-17 09:27:00',    124 from dual union all
select 10, '2020-08-13 00:00:00','Wednesday' ,'2020-08-13 11:35:00', '2020-08-13 12:11:00', 36 from dual union all
select 11, '2022-09-27 00:00:00', 'Thursday','2022-09-27 07:29:00', '2022-09-27 09:05:00',  96 from dual union all
select 12, '2023-02-14 00:00:00','Friday' ,'2023-02-14 14:18:00', '2023-02-14 14:41:00',    23 from dual union all
select 13, '2023-07-14 00:00:00','Saturday' ,'2023-07-14 08:36:00', '2023-07-14 09:20:00',  44 from dual union all
select 14, '2023-03-28 00:00:00','Sunday' ,'2023-03-28 10:03:00', '2023-03-28 10:29:00',    26 from dual union all
select 15, '2023-06-12 00:00:00','Monday' ,'2023-06-12 07:35:00', '2023-06-12 10:48:00',    193 from dual

)
```

Here's the rest of my code:

```
ROOM_TIMES AS (
    
    SELECT
        LOG_ID
        , CASE WHEN DAY_OF_WEEK = 'Wednesday'
            THEN TO_DATE ( CONCAT( SB_OR_CASES.SURGERY_DATE, ' 08:30:00' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
            ELSE TO_DATE ( CONCAT( SB_OR_CASES.SURGERY_DATE, ' 07:30:00' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) 
         END AS ROOM_START_TM
         , TO_DATE ( CONCAT( SB_OR_CASES.SURGERY_DATE, ' 17:00:00' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS ROOM_END_TM
     FROM 
         SB_OR_CASES
    ),

FILTERED_SB_OR_CASES AS (

SELECT 
SB_OR_CASES.*
, CASE
  WHEN ( SB_OR_CASES.IN_OR_DTTM < ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_START_TM AND SB_OR_CASES.OUT_OR_DTTM <= ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_END_TM )
       THEN ( ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_START_TM - SB_OR_CASES.OUT_OR_DTTM )*24*60
  WHEN ( SB_OR_CASES.IN_OR_DTTM < ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_START_TM AND SB_OR_CASES.OUT_OR_DTTM > ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_END_TM )
       THEN 0
  WHEN ( SB_OR_CASES.IN_OR_DTTM >= ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_START_TM AND SB_OR_CASES.OUT_OR_DTTM > ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_END_TM )
       THEN ( SB_OR_CASES.IN_OR_DTTM - ROOM_TIMES.ROOM_END_TM )*24*60
       ELSE SB_OR_CASES.MINUTES_IN_OR
  END AS CORRECT_OR_LOG
FROM 
    SB_OR_CASES
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ROOM_TIMES ON SB_OR_CASES.LOG_ID = ROOM_TIMES.LOG_ID
WHERE 
    ( SB_OR_CASES.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 'Sunday', 'Saturday' ) ) 
)
```

My default date format in Oracle SQL Developer is YYYY-MM-DD.
I've also tried CONCAT ( TRUNC (SB_OR_CASES.SURGERY_DATE, ' 8:30:00') and I ran into this error: ORA-01722: invalid number.

My goal is to temporarily add 7:30:00 (or 8:30:00) and 17:00:00 to each date depending on the day of week. If IN_OR_DTTM and OUT_OR_DTTM is after hours (not between 7:30 am and 5 pm (8:30 am to 5 pm on Wed), then I want the total duration minutes equal to 0. If the case starts earlier than 7:30 (or 8:30 on Wed), then count the minutes from when the room opened to when the case ended. If the case ended after 5pm, then calculate the total duration from when the case started to when the room closed (5pm).

Thank you, I appreciate any help!

Comment: show the desired output for given sample data as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert the values from strings to `DATE`s.
2. Don't try to concatenate strings to change the time; just add a `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.
3. You don't need to know `day_of_week` as you can derive it (independently of language) by subtracting the date from the start of the ISO week (always midnight on Monday) using `surgery_date - TRUNC(surgery_date, 'IW')`.
4. You do not need to find the room times as a separate table; you can generate it as part of the calculation which eliminates the (expensive) `JOIN`.
5. It is much simpler to use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to find the time difference than a `CASE` expression.

Like this:

```sql
with sb_or_cases (log_id, surgery_date, day_of_week, in_or_dttm, out_or_dttm, minutes_in_or) as 
(
  select  1, '2023-07-18 00:00:00', 'Monday',    '2023-07-18 08:44:00', '2023-07-18 09:10:00',  26 from dual union all
  select  2, '2023-01-24 00:00:00', 'Tuesday',   '2023-01-24 12:39:00', '2023-01-24 13:28:00',  49 from dual union all
  select  3, '2022-05-16 00:00:00', 'Wednesday', '2022-05-16 07:30:00', '2022-05-16 08:12:00',  42 from dual union all
  select  4, '2023-04-04 00:00:00', 'Thursday',  '2023-04-04 10:10:00', '2023-04-04 10:32:00',  22 from dual union all
  select  5, '2023-07-26 00:00:00', 'Friday',    '2023-07-26 08:34:00', '2023-07-26 09:20:00',  46 from dual union all
  select  6, '2022-11-22 00:00:00', 'Saturday',  '2022-11-22 07:24:00', '2022-11-22 08:20:00',  56 from dual union all
  select  7, '2023-05-04 00:00:00', 'Sunday',    '2023-05-04 11:44:00', '2023-05-04 12:07:00',  23 from dual union all
  select  8, '2022-06-01 00:00:00', 'Monday',    '2022-06-01 09:38:00', '2022-06-01 10:31:00',  53 from dual union all
  select  9, '2022-11-17 00:00:00', 'Tuesday',   '2022-11-17 07:23:00', '2022-11-17 09:27:00', 124 from dual union all
  select 10, '2020-08-13 00:00:00', 'Wednesday', '2020-08-13 11:35:00', '2020-08-13 12:11:00',  36 from dual union all
  select 11, '2022-09-27 00:00:00', 'Thursday',  '2022-09-27 07:29:00', '2022-09-27 09:05:00',  96 from dual union all
  select 12, '2023-02-14 00:00:00', 'Friday',    '2023-02-14 14:18:00', '2023-02-14 14:41:00',  23 from dual union all
  select 13, '2023-07-14 00:00:00', 'Saturday',  '2023-07-14 08:36:00', '2023-07-14 09:20:00',  44 from dual union all
  select 14, '2023-03-28 00:00:00', 'Sunday',    '2023-03-28 10:03:00', '2023-03-28 10:29:00',  26 from dual union all
  select 15, '2023-06-12 00:00:00', 'Monday',    '2023-06-12 07:35:00', '2023-06-12 10:48:00', 193 from dual union all
  select 16, '2023-06-12 00:00:00', 'Monday',    '2023-06-12 07:15:00', '2023-06-12 07:23:00',   8 from dual union all
  select 17, '2023-06-12 00:00:00', 'Monday',    '2023-06-12 17:35:00', '2023-06-12 17:43:00',   8 from dual
),
sb_or_cases_dates(log_id, surgery_date, day_of_week, in_or_dttm, out_or_dttm, minutes_in_or) AS (
  SELECT log_id,
         TO_DATE(surgery_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(surgery_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'fxDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
         TO_DATE(in_or_dttm,   'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         TO_DATE(out_or_dttm,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         minutes_in_or
  FROM   sb_or_cases
)
SELECT s.*,
       ROUND(
         GREATEST(
           LEAST(
             out_or_dttm,
             surgery_date + INTERVAL '17:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
           )
           -
           GREATEST(
             in_or_dttm, 
             CASE
             WHEN surgery_date - TRUNC(surgery_date, 'IW') = 2 -- Wednesday
             THEN surgery_date + INTERVAL '08:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND
             ELSE surgery_date + INTERVAL '07:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND
             END
           ),
           0
         ) * 24 * 60
       ) AS correct_or_log
FROM   sb_or_cases_dates s
WHERE  surgery_date - TRUNC(surgery_date, 'IW') < 5 -- Weekdays
```

*Note: rows 16 and 17 test data that is entirely either before or after the working day.*

Which outputs:

| LOG_ID | SURGERY_DATE | DAY_OF_WEEK | IN_OR_DTTM | OUT_OR_DTTM | MINUTES_IN_OR | CORRECT_OR_LOG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-07-18 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2023-07-18 08:44:00 | 2023-07-18 09:10:00 | 26 | 26 |
| 2 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2023-01-24 12:39:00 | 2023-01-24 13:28:00 | 49 | 49 |
| 3 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00 | Monday | 2022-05-16 07:30:00 | 2022-05-16 08:12:00 | 42 | 42 |
| 4 | 2023-04-04 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2023-04-04 10:10:00 | 2023-04-04 10:32:00 | 22 | 22 |
| 5 | 2023-07-26 00:00:00 | Wednesday | 2023-07-26 08:34:00 | 2023-07-26 09:20:00 | 46 | 46 |
| 6 | 2022-11-22 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2022-11-22 07:24:00 | 2022-11-22 08:20:00 | 56 | 50 |
| 7 | 2023-05-04 00:00:00 | Thursday | 2023-05-04 11:44:00 | 2023-05-04 12:07:00 | 23 | 23 |
| 8 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | Wednesday | 2022-06-01 09:38:00 | 2022-06-01 10:31:00 | 53 | 53 |
| 9 | 2022-11-17 00:00:00 | Thursday | 2022-11-17 07:23:00 | 2022-11-17 09:27:00 | 124 | 117 |
| 10 | 2020-08-13 00:00:00 | Thursday | 2020-08-13 11:35:00 | 2020-08-13 12:11:00 | 36 | 36 |
| 11 | 2022-09-27 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2022-09-27 07:29:00 | 2022-09-27 09:05:00 | 96 | 95 |
| 12 | 2023-02-14 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2023-02-14 14:18:00 | 2023-02-14 14:41:00 | 23 | 23 |
| 13 | 2023-07-14 00:00:00 | Friday | 2023-07-14 08:36:00 | 2023-07-14 09:20:00 | 44 | 44 |
| 14 | 2023-03-28 00:00:00 | Tuesday | 2023-03-28 10:03:00 | 2023-03-28 10:29:00 | 26 | 26 |
| 15 | 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | Monday | 2023-06-12 07:35:00 | 2023-06-12 10:48:00 | 193 | 193 |
| 16 | 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | Monday | 2023-06-12 07:15:00 | 2023-06-12 07:23:00 | 8 | 0 |
| 17 | 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | Monday | 2023-06-12 17:35:00 | 2023-06-12 17:43:00 | 8 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Zjx7nH7)

Answer (score 1):

Your **worst** problem is that you're storing dates as strings (at least, that's what sample data suggest). Therefore, I'd suggest you to **first** convert them to proper datatype (`date`), and the rest is then simple.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with sb_or_cases (log_id, surgery_date, day_of_week, in_or_dttm, out_or_dttm, minutes_in_or) as
  2  (
  3  select 1, '2023-07-18 00:00:00', 'Monday' ,'2023-07-18 08:44:00', '2023-07-18 09:10:00', 26 from dual union all
  4  select 2, '2023-01-24 00:00:00','Tuesday' ,'2023-01-24 12:39:00', '2023-01-24 13:28:00', 49 from dual union all
  5  select 3, '2022-05-16 00:00:00', 'Wednesday','2022-05-16 07:30:00', '2022-05-16 08:12:00', 42 from dual union all
  6  select 4, '2023-04-04 00:00:00', 'Thursday','2023-04-04 10:10:00', '2023-04-04 10:32:00', 22 from dual union all
  7  select 5, '2023-07-26 00:00:00','Friday' ,'2023-07-26 08:34:00', '2023-07-26 09:20:00', 46 from dual union all
  8  select 6, '2022-11-22 00:00:00','Saturday' ,'2022-11-22 07:24:00', '2022-11-22 08:20:00',   56 from dual union all
  9  select 7, '2023-05-04 00:00:00', 'Sunday' ,'2023-05-04 11:44:00', '2023-05-04 12:07:00',    23 from dual union all
 10  select 8, '2022-06-01 00:00:00', 'Monday' ,'2022-06-01 09:38:00', '2022-06-01 10:31:00',    53 from dual union all
 11  select 9, '2022-11-17 00:00:00','Tuesday' ,'2022-11-17 07:23:00', '2022-11-17 09:27:00',    124 from dual union all
 12  select 10, '2020-08-13 00:00:00','Wednesday' ,'2020-08-13 11:35:00', '2020-08-13 12:11:00', 36 from dual union all
 13  select 11, '2022-09-27 00:00:00', 'Thursday','2022-09-27 07:29:00', '2022-09-27 09:05:00',  96 from dual union all
 14  select 12, '2023-02-14 00:00:00','Friday' ,'2023-02-14 14:18:00', '2023-02-14 14:41:00',    23 from dual union all
 15  select 13, '2023-07-14 00:00:00','Saturday' ,'2023-07-14 08:36:00', '2023-07-14 09:20:00',  44 from dual union all
 16  select 14, '2023-03-28 00:00:00','Sunday' ,'2023-03-28 10:03:00', '2023-03-28 10:29:00',    26 from dual union all
 17  select 15, '2023-06-12 00:00:00','Monday' ,'2023-06-12 07:35:00', '2023-06-12 10:48:00',    193 from dual
 18  ),
```

Query begins here; read comments within code. I didn't include *all* `WHEN` clauses as you did; one of them should be enough to do the rest yourself.

```
 19  new_sb_or_cases as
 20    -- first convert strings to dates, to make your life easier
 21    (select log_id,
 22            to_date(surgery_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') surgery_date,
 23            day_of_week,
 24            to_date(in_or_dttm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') in_or_dttm,
 25            to_date(out_or_dttm, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') out_or_dttm,
 26            minutes_in_or
 27     from sb_or_cases
 28    ),
 29  room_times as
 30    -- calculate ROOM values in a simpler manner - no more datatype conversion!
 31    (select log_id,
 32       surgery_date + (case when day_of_week = 'Wednesday' then 8 else 7 end) / 24 + 30/(24*60) as room_start_tm,
 33       surgery_date + 17/24 as room_end_tm
 34     from new_sb_or_cases
 35    )
 36  -- finally, a simple comparison
 37  select s.*,
 38    case when s.in_or_dttm  <  r.room_start_tm and
 39              s.out_or_dttm <= r.room_end_tm
 40         then (r.room_start_tm - s.out_or_dttm) * 24 * 60
 41    end as correct_or_log
 42  from new_sb_or_cases s join room_times r on s.log_id = r.log_id;

    LOG_ID SURGERY_ DAY_OF_WE IN_OR_DT OUT_OR_D MINUTES_IN_OR CORRECT_OR_LOG
---------- -------- --------- -------- -------- ------------- --------------
         1 18.07.23 Monday    18.07.23 18.07.23            26
         2 24.01.23 Tuesday   24.01.23 24.01.23            49
         3 16.05.22 Wednesday 16.05.22 16.05.22            42             18
         4 04.04.23 Thursday  04.04.23 04.04.23            22
         5 26.07.23 Friday    26.07.23 26.07.23            46
         6 22.11.22 Saturday  22.11.22 22.11.22            56            -50
         7 04.05.23 Sunday    04.05.23 04.05.23            23
         8 01.06.22 Monday    01.06.22 01.06.22            53
         9 17.11.22 Tuesday   17.11.22 17.11.22           124           -117
        10 13.08.20 Wednesday 13.08.20 13.08.20            36
        11 27.09.22 Thursday  27.09.22 27.09.22            96            -95
        12 14.02.23 Friday    14.02.23 14.02.23            23
        13 14.07.23 Saturday  14.07.23 14.07.23            44
        14 28.03.23 Sunday    28.03.23 28.03.23            26
        15 12.06.23 Monday    12.06.23 12.06.23           193

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```